# A question of a A. Dow's 2002 paper

Tags: general-topology

As the title explains, I would like to understand the Example(4.3)(4), Page 195 of the paper. However, the last part I cannot pass which said: Let us finally prove that $X$ is not weakly discretely generated.

> A space is called weakly discretely generated if for every $A\subset X$ with $cl(A)\not=A$ there is a discrete $D\subset A$ such that $cl(D)\setminus A \not=\emptyset$.

[Here is the paper link](http://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=zh-JP&source=hp&q=topologies%20generated%20discrete%20subspaces&gbv=2&oq=topologies%20generated%20discrete%20subspaces&gs_l=heirloom-hp.12...3938.39063.0.40360.26.25.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.4j1.4x4B4di1mdE). Thanks for any help.

Comment: The command for the set difference operator is `\setminus`. (By the way, the title doesn't explain what you say it explains.)

Comment: It seems you are talking about [this paper](http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/glasnik/vol_37/no1_16.html). Please clarify (and mention the three other authors if my guess is correct). Linking to the results of Google Japan is not very helpful (most people don't speak Japanese) and one still has to guess which search result you actually mean.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? The question as you posted it is very general and would require one to read a good portion of the paper before answering your question (unless one is already familiar with the subject matter of the paper). I would at least give a brief description of the context, and describe where I was getting stuck. At least tell us what $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ means. Anyway, it seems that one only needs to understand that $C$ is maximal and maximality implies that every discrete subspace of $C$ is closed. Given these, the rest of the proof is trivial.

Comment: @Paul: You could simply [ask Dow](http://math.uncc.edu/~adow/). FYI, my undergraduate and Masters degrees (both in mathematics) are from the department he is at, although he was not there when I was a student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}C$ is a dense subset of $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ of cardinality $2^\omega$. $C$ is dense-in-itself, so its relative topology can be refined to a maximal dense-in-itself topology $\mu$. $X$ is $\langle\beta\omega\setminus\omega,\nu\rangle$, where $\nu$ is the topology generated by the subbase $\tau\cup\mu$, where $\tau$ is the usual topology on $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$.

Now let $x\in C$, and suppose that $A\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$ with $x\in\cl_\nu A$. $C\in\mu\subseteq\nu$, so $C$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$. Let $A_0=C\cap A$, and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$; then $U\cap C$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so $$U\cap A_0=(U\cap C)\cap A\ne\varnothing\;,$$ and therefore $x\in\cl_\nu A_0$. But the relative topology on $C$ as a subspace of $X$ is $\mu$, so $\cl_\nu A_0=\cl_\mu A_0$, and $x\in\cl_\mu A_0$.

Now suppose that $A$ is discrete in $X$; clearly $A_0$ is discrete in $C$. Suppose that $y$ is an isolated point of $C\setminus A_0$; then $y$ has an open nbhd $U\subseteq\{y\}\cup A_0$. But this is impossible: clearly $U$ cannot be dense-in-itself, but $C$ is dense-in-itself, so every non-empty open subset of $C$ is dense-in-itself. Thus, $C\setminus A_0$ is dense-in-itself. Let

$$\begin{align*}
\mu'&=\left\{U\cup\big(V\cap(C\setminus A_0)\big):U,V\in\mu\right\}\\
&=\left\{U\cup(V\setminus A_0):U,V\in\mu\right\}\;;
\end{align*}$$

then $\mu'$ is a topology on $C$, $\mu'\supseteq\mu$, and we just showed that $\langle C,\mu'\rangle$ has no isolated points. By the maximality of $\mu$ we must have $\mu'=\mu$ and hence $V\setminus A_0\in\mu$, i.e., $A_0$ is closed in $C$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $x\in(\cl_\mu A_0)\setminus A_0$, thereby showing that $A$ cannot be discrete in $X$ and hence that $X$ is not weakly discretely generated. (Specifically, for any $x\in X$ the set $A=X\setminus\{x\}$ fails the condition of Definition 3.2: there is no discrete $D\subseteq A$ such that $(\cl D)\setminus A\ne\varnothing$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why $C$ is dense in itsef?

Comment: Second: By your proof, can we say, if $C$ is maximal, then any discrete subset of $C$ is closed in $C$?

Comment: @Paul: $C$ is dense-in-itself in $\tau$ because $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ is dense-in-itself, and $C$ is dense in $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$. Yes, every $\mu$-discrete subset of $C$ is $\mu$-closed in $C$. (Sorry to be so slow.)